# Typescript: Type of a property dependent on another property within the same object

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have a TypeScript interface with two properties (`type:string` and `args:object`). The `args` may have different properties depending on the `type`. What type definition to I need to apply to `args` so the compiler/autocomplete will know which properties are allowed for `args`?

This is somewhat similar to how I use Actions in Redux, which do have a `type` and a `payload` and in my reducer the compiler knows by the switch-statement what the payload contains. But I can't get this to work with my object.
I have read an excellent article here https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/ but this describes the problem for a method with two args which depend on one another but not how to get this working for two properties within the same object.

```js
export interface IObject {
  type: ObjectType
  parameters: ObjectParameters
}
```

```js
export type ObjectType = "check" | "counter"
```

```js
export interface IParametersCheck {
  checked: boolean
}
```

```js
export interface IParametersCounter {
  max: number
  min: number
  step: number
}
```

```js
export type ObjectParameters = IParametersCheck | IParametersCounter
```

If I have an `IObject` and set the type to "check" the compiler/autocomplete should offer the properties for `IParametersCheck`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a connection between the `type` and the `parameters`, so I am not sure if you could set this restriction. Maybe wherever you create your actions, you could use a generic type instead and define it as `IObject<ParameterType>`?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I think what you are actually looking for is a discriminated union. `IObject` should itself be a union:

```
export type IObject = {
    type: "checked"
    parameters: IParametersCheck
} | {
    type: "counter"
    parameters: IParametersCounter
}
export type ObjectType = IObject['type'] //// in case you need this union
export type ObjectParameters = IObject['parameters']  //// in case you need this union

export interface IParametersCheck {
    checked: boolean
}
export interface IParametersCounter {
    max: number
    min: number
    step: number
}
```

You could also do it with conditional types but I think the union solution works better :

```
export interface IObject<T extends ObjectType> {
    type: T
    parameters: T extends 'checked' ? IParametersCheck: IParametersCounter
}
```

Or with a mapping interface:

```
export interface IObject<T extends ObjectType> {
    type: T
    parameters: ParameterMap[T]
}
type ParameterMap ={
    'checked': IParametersCheck
    'counter': IParametersCounter
}

export type ObjectType = keyof ParameterMap
```