# Is recursive array types possible in union discrimination?

Tags: arrays, typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

I'm just starting discovering TypeScript and I'm testing the limits. What I'm looking for is a way to make an interface that as fields depending on the value of one of it's property.

For example:

```
type type RecursiveArray<T> = T | RecursiveArray<T>[];
type allowedTypesString = 'string' | 'email' | 'date' | 'id' | 'number' | 'boolean' | 'object';


interface IOptions {
    type: RecursiveArray<allowedTypesString>,
    required?: boolean,
    defaultValue?: PROVIDED_TYPE,
    expected?: PROVIDED_TYPE[],
    transform?: (value: PROVIDED_TYPE) => any,
    validate?: (value: PROVIDED_TYPE) => boolean,
    regexp?: RegExp,
    min?: number,
    max?: number,
    params?: object,
}
```

I want IOptions to have:

- `regex` property only if `type` is "string" or "email" .
- `params` only if `type` is "object".
- `min` and `max` only if `type` is "number, etc...

I saw that I could use discriminated unions like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj) thread, but as you can see, the `type` property is a `RecursiveArray<allowedTypesString>` which means that it can be a **single string**, an **array of string**, an **array of array of string**, *etc*...

With unions, I could declare :

```
interface IOptionsString {
    type: string,
    defaultValue?: string,
    expected?: string[],
    regexp?: RegExp,
}
```

that will be called if the `type` is a string. But what if I'm receiving an **array of string** or an **array of array of string** ?

Is what I'm doing possible ? Otherwise I'll just handle single array but I want to know if what I'm thinking of is possible in TypeScript.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want with conditional types if you parameterize `IOptions` with the actual type and then turn into an intersection of common types and special ones that depend on the type.

To go back to the original types (i.e. `PROVIDED_TYPE` in your example) you need to change `allowedTypesString` into a map from string types to actual types and then use conditional types to reify (i.e. convert from value to type).

```js
type RecursiveArray<T> = T | RecursiveArray<T>[];

interface TypeStringMap {
  'string': string;
  'email': string;
  'date': Date;
  'id': string;
  'number': number;
  'boolean': boolean;
  'object': object;
}

type RecursiveTypes = RecursiveArray<keyof TypeStringMap>;

type HasRegexp<T extends RecursiveTypes> =
  T extends RecursiveArray<'string' | 'email'> ? { regexp: RegExp } : {}

type HasMinMax<T extends RecursiveTypes> =
  T extends RecursiveArray<'number'> ? { min: number, max: number } : {}

type ReifyRecursiveType<T> =
  T extends keyof TypeStringMap ? TypeStringMap[T]
  : (T extends (infer U)[] ? ReifyRecursiveType<U>[] : never)

type IOptions<T extends RecursiveTypes> = {
  type: T;
  expected?: ReifyRecursiveType<T>[];
  defaultValue?: ReifyRecursiveType<T>,
  transform?: <TResult>(value: ReifyRecursiveType<T>) => TResult,
  validate?: (value: ReifyRecursiveType<T>) => boolean,
} & HasRegexp<T> & HasMinMax<T>

type IStringOptions = IOptions<'string'>; // has `regexp` field
type IStringOrEmailOptions = IOptions<('string' | 'email')>; // has `regexp` field
type IEmailArrayArrayOptions = IOptions<'email'[][]>; // has `regexp` field
type INumberOptions = IOptions<'number'>; // has `min` and `max` fields
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I just have a question about the fields where I put "PROVIDED_TYPE", how can I transform the type "string" to the real string type ? 

Also, how can I tell if it's a string, an array of string or more ?

For example, if T is an array of string, I want the `expected` field to be an array of array of string. Is that possible ?

Comment: @GaldanM I've updated the answer with the information

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, thanks a lot for your update, I think I understand TypeScript much better now. But this solution still isn't working unfortunately...

In fact, the IOptions will be used in another interface like that :

`interface IParams {
 [key: string]: IOptions
}`

Problem is that `IOptions` ask for a type, so I tried to put `IOptions<RecursiveTypes>`, it looks like it's working, but when a create an object of type `IParams`, if I put `type` to "string", the `max` property is allowed when it should not...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Also, if I put `defaultValue` as ['foo', 'bar'], when type is "string", I don't get an error but `defaultValue` should be of the same type as `type`