# TypeScript dependent string literal properties and indexing

Tags: typescript

Similar to [Typescript: Type of a property dependent on another property within the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj) I want a type where the properties are dependent.

```js
const attributes = {
    physical: {
        traits: {
            strength: 1,
            dexterity: 1,
            stamina: 1,
        }
    },
    social: {
        traits: {
            charisma: 1,
            manipulation: 1,
            appearance: 1,
        }
    },
    mental: {
        traits: {
            perception: 1,
            intelligence: 1,
            wits: 1,
        }
    }
};

type AttributeTrait =
    | {
        category: 'physical';
        trait: keyof typeof attributes.physical.traits;
    }
    | {
        category: 'social';
        trait: keyof typeof attributes.social.traits;
    }
    | {
        category: 'mental';
        trait: keyof typeof attributes.mental.traits;
    };

const action: AttributeTrait = {
    category: 'social',
    trait: 'manipulation'
}

function increment(action: AttributeTrait) {
    attributes[action.category].traits[action.trait]++; // error 7053
}
```

In the function, `action.trait` is typed as:

> (property) trait: "strength" | "dexterity" | "stamina" | "charisma" | "manipulation" | "appearance" | "perception" | "intelligence" | "wits"

so it can't be used to index `traits`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like another question to add to growing pile I have in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)... this is what I've been calling a "correlated record type" and there's no great support for it.  Redundant code, type assertions, or complete refactoring are the only solutions I can suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a non-redundant and type safe solution for you.  Your `AttributeTrait` is something I've been calling a [correlated record type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  It's a discriminated union where some bit of code is safe for each member of the union, but the compiler cannot see that it safe for the union as a whole, because it loses track of the *correlation* between the `category` and `trait` properties.

If you write redundant code, the error goes away:

```
function incrementRedundant(action: AttributeTrait) {
    switch (action.category) {
        case "physical":
            attributes[action.category].traits[action.trait]++;
            return;
        case "social":
            attributes[action.category].traits[action.trait]++;
            return;
        case "mental":
            attributes[action.category].traits[action.trait]++;
            return;
    }
}
```

But try as you might, you can't collapse those cases into a single line of code and get the compiler to verify safety for you.  That's why I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and one reason I had filed [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051).  Since you can't ask the compiler to treat the single line *as if* it had been written out in a `switch`/`case` statement, the best thing I can think of is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know better than it does.

One way to do this is to lie a little bit and tell the compiler that `attributes` actually has all `trait`s on all `category` objects:

```
function increment(action: AttributeTrait) {
    (attributes as
        Record<AttributeTrait["category"], {
            traits: Record<AttributeTrait["trait"], number>
        }>
    )[action.category].traits[action.trait]++;
}
```

This is less type safe than the redundant code, but at least it lets you move forward.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhlKAnAlgIwK5QKYRgXhgG8AoGcmABwAsBPCFYOAGwC5iyKvk4UoJ2pLsIrQk2MAHMo1dgEYANJxFcAJtgAeOVFFrylK4dDgBbFGDj7lwgL7WbB0SGAoWg69yS9+7w12DUcKgQJpYwih4qoWAolBjMCCjgVn4UcJSU2EFwYMDYKSp2XA7WJhJQbhyGPHwCValU2Eh5lFBJYAWp5jjMzCiSEnmdfgDutcPF9iQ2ANwkJLqZMACCiKiYOAAqXnwE1gA+9SJMOJIgSHowAOQ09IwsV3PVO1DsANbYtCAAZjCL2D94Gt0FhcAA6W4MJjMME1fhPChFCiHIQqE7YM4XdhXCDOVzMR6Rchw96fQH-QEIZAgnAQMG4lwsWEvCAI8hI8gookwdGYy5XMpgCoEtnCEkwD5fX4U35U9agumC4XM7ys+xzEigSCwODANrJFbAjbYbbeAhHHkIDHnfkM-FXRzEl7Y6KxeKJcBXabzb4YXL6sAwczAcRKgBK2FUftUOSgAApdQH2KtqcbTXwAJQWiBjKABGAJvXtMG8m1Z1HHOAQbAwABEkPuzFrrG5XDlNNwAG1E8XSxcALoq2rdovgIdQfsAaknosM4igGCQYFnFCY1brdpYzdbaSNCpHAZLVr5g7hEAPxbhU5nO-I88Xy+5a5rtaVW5bDSBqf3PbHfdop4sheY5XtOK4iPeS6inYdgkL6-rtEGuShuUhZJoa35bC85bWAme60vAEDchGoBIKoAA8Kbylh3idrW-61v2CgWs8qrsCR5wUVRHbplAdFwoxzFgBgJhoE0AB83I2JJXAZsBYBHqcNqAaq8njtecywUAA)