# TypeScript: Type of function that uses discriminated union gives error

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

In my file, I have the following discriminated union type

```
interface SlackStageQuery {
  stage: 'slack';
}

interface GithubStageQuery {
  stage: 'github';
  id: string;
}

interface SuccessStageQuery {
  stage: 'success';
  name: string;
  link: string;
}

type StageQuery = SlackStageQuery | GithubStageQuery | SuccessStageQuery;
```

Additionally, I have the following interface:

```
interface Details<S extends OnboardingStage> {
  position: number;
  title: S extends 'success' ? (name: string) => string : string;
  subtitle: string;
  button: (query: StageQuery & { stage: S }) => JSX.Element;
}
```

Then, I have an arbitrary object `ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS` which conforms to `{ [p in OnboardingStage]: Details<p> }`.

I also have a `query` variable of type `StageQuery`.

To get the `button` property from one of the sub-objects of `ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS`, I do

```
const foo = ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS[query.stage].button(query)
```

For some reason however, I get this type error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'StageQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.   Type 'SlackStageQuery' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I'm not sure why this is, since, for example, if `query.stage === 'slack'`, then `ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS[query.stage]` would be of type `Details<'slack'>`, whose `button` property takes a `StageQuery & { stage: 'slack' }`, which it is being provided. So I would think all the types would be able to work.

Anyone know why this is and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This is another instance of TypeScript's lack of good support for what I've been calling "correlated union types".  I'll add it to the list at [microsoft/TypeScript#35810](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  You can see the answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61450183/typescript-dependent-string-literal-properties-and-indexing) for details.  The choices you have are either writing redundant code or writing less type-safe code: see [this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKkrKW).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot fully explain the type error, but I feel as though it is because `query` is a union type at compile time, then the inferred type of the parameter in the `button(query) {}` method will also be a union, and somehow/somewhere the intersection with `{ stage : }` cannot be resolved, hence the `never` type was resolved.

---

Thinking out loud here...

```
declare const query: StageQuery;
const details = ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS[query.stage];    // (1)

details.button(query);    // (2)
```

(1): `query` is of type `SlackStageQuery | GithubStageQuery | SuccessStageQuery`.
`query.stage` is of type `OnboardingStage`, which is a union type of `"success" | "slack" | "github"`.
So `details` is of type `Details<S>` where `S = OnboardingStage`.

(2): Expanding the type of the parameter of `details.button()`:

```
StageQuery & { stage: S }
=> StageQuery & { stage: "success" | "slack" | "github" }
=> (SlackStageQuery | GithubStageQuery | SuccessStageQuery) & { stage: "success" | "slack" | "github" }
=> (SlackStageQuery & { stage: "success" | "slack" | "github" }) | ...
=> /* typescript internal type resolution */
=> never(?!)
```

If anyone else can figure out how this resolves to `never`, or whether this is the correct approach to debugging the type resolution, I'd be very happy to learn too :)

---

As for how to fix, you can take advantage of [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to redefine your interface to avoid the intersection type altogether:

```
interface Details<Query extends StageQuery> {
               // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~note the change here
  position: number;
  title: Query["stage"] extends 'success' ? (name: string) => string : string;
  subtitle: string;
  button: (query: Query) => any;
}

type OnboardingStage = StageQuery["stage"];

declare const ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS: {
    [query in StageQuery as StageQuery["stage"]]: Details<query>
    // ^~~~~ map over the StageQueries, but the object is indexed by StageQuery["stage"]
}

declare const query: StageQuery;
ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS[query.stage].button(query)  // OK! :)

const ghdetails: Details<GithubStageQuery> = {
  position: 1,
  title: "",
  subtitle: "",
  button: (query) => { /*query inferred as GitHubQuery */}
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIBcE8AcFNwHkB2AjA9gQwE4BMBLFAcwGVItjEBecAIgGcBXAYxfgYbvAB96GANlhYBrbnzrECkABZM0dYMCKR4OAGbDEpIaPKV4ARSZro4AN7Bw4BhSoAucAHJBwkU4DcwAL5KVazXZwAHFpOTR9KmNTCysbO3hHJylZeU84gjxHWxwiYi9fZRRVDS1wUlZ2TkijExwzS2tbAyTmNg4GdOsULABbRPjcki9rASIRbMgh-J8lGARyhOj68FodNxrlsz5Q1Iiluu3yyo7Nw7m4RFRMXEISGtXFgy2AbUYEugBdJTx4FiEcIgWBgULZwABHQ6OM6mLxgcC-f64IEgsHNBxPKKHN7o+BfPzFAJlAAi8AoBAEDAAPFtwPAAB6qFB4BiY2qmAB8sWssAwDGkBBBjhQTF6aDUIyg0gEA1e7wMXzpjPgzNZLhOnCc4AA-OAABQ9fqTaYASlWXJyeXAxrykuYaEg0oGluGcTQTEgkCF+shpkcWzN1C5WBQ0AKSmBoMg4GIMl+5MpjlJCepu3CMPqXNojXAvP5ju9AEYADRxR2QGWOOh0UtNeTlyv0Gtuj1elCOPW++qBrnmXyFREAlFR5AAOQAQkgAIIAJWJAElR8EAPqkAAqU+CAFFl8Stxv5wAZUiOczgF5dsxENm0rCsjPQHEfT6fJNkrAU6mXrmFJAT6dzouK7rpuO57gex4XocAB0uKfNB7qeiCnaHCaSggAAVBhVgYeAyYfpSVKkEqTIsvQWB0DwdBoFRLB0ByOHgIxD7gAAZBYuJVhRVEKLRdC+OAuGMXqhiFrw4CGAATOJhgAMxmux5iceRlHUapdECUJgnIGJ7HKXQ3FqXxjE4SAQA)

Comment: @Andson Miu that mostly works, however this now breaks: `query.stage === 'success' ? ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS[query.stage].title(query.name)
  : ONBOARDING_STAGE_DETAILS[query.stage].title`

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using an union type already (`StageQuery`) you don't need to also use an intersection (every variable of type `StageQuery` will already have a `stage` property) so you can simply remove it and the code will work:

```
interface Details<S extends OnboardingStage> {
  position: number;
  title: S extends 'success' ? (name: string) => string : string;
  subtitle: string;
  button: (query: StageQuery) => any;
}
```

Link to a playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoBtEGtVjgcwgEUBXaAT2QG8AoZZAZz0IC5kByBzBLdgbhoBfGjVCRYiFAHFgYABYkARrgLEyUSrXpNVbdvlkLF-OsmAATNkyih8A4aPDR4SNCQRIGDFYVIVqpjqsHAzungwm9CBwALYQVmA2IHam6KBYCUkpDmDkAA4oPmr+ALxo3DjMxRrIAD7IMvJKRX419ahhEF4t6uQCNLkFyADyIIoA9nBQ5rZFyGWcFex1HAZNxiucnV4mjuIuKAAiEHjA6AwAPKjIEAAekCDmDCNjk9OzVQB8AfR54wyyYDjEBsEAkGKKaACehgWToeJoG73CCPZ5bDxdCLIAD8yAAFNE4plbABKebfay2ZDE5LQxhKWFgeE0lL0RQkMBgYFsPEAR16bB6FDJJW+cBAfSEInMEAQmCgKAQwKYyH5FEFVVakpoMrlU0VyrAIwAcgAhYYAQQASocAJLGqQAfVQABULVIAKKOw4et22gAyqDYVGQAG0AApmEAvCZTGbJIoAXTYx1O5wu4e+gn6SpAKpg43G8xN5utdodzrdnu9votAdQobVGgAdEEIInm+zOcC+b0SXwgA

Comment: I think the OP's intention of using the intersection type is to define specialised objects that implement the `Details` interface with `button` methods that take the _specific_ query type in its parameter, e.g. some `successDetails` object of type `Details<"success">` that has method `button(query: SuccessQuery)`

Comment: @AnsonMiu Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In that case there was nothing wrong with it. Have a look at the edited playground.