# Property type depending on type of other property

Tags: typescript, types

So I'm testing TypeScript in how far I can take it and cannot seem to get past the following issue.
How can I limit the type of property B when property A has some value?

```
// The type I want to declare
type Bar<T> = {
    prop: keyof T; // Select a property of the type
    value: T[keyof T]; // Provide the value of that property, this currently does not work
}

// Some random interface
interface Foo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

let bar: Bar<Foo> = {
    prop: "name", // Selected Foo.name: string
    value: 9,     // Should only allow strings
};
```

The property type of `value` in this case is `number | string`, but I would like to force it to string since the selected property `name` is of type `string`.

---

**Notes**

I can declare it this way, but the interface is a lot less appealing, clear and is more error prone: only one property should be selectable and you don't really know what is expected since property names are absent. Or I need to nest objects even further.

```
type Bar<T> = {
    prop: {
        [K in keyof T]?: T[K];
    }
}

let bar: Bar<Foo> = {
    prop: {
        name: 'yay', // string is forced now
    }
};
```

- [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj). I guess this only works when the values are known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Foo has two keys one of type string and number the other. Therefore value is string | number. Maybe this works?

```
// The type I want to declare
type Bar<T, U> = {
    prop: keyof T; // Select a property of the type
    value: U; // Provide the value of that property, this currently does not work
}

// Some random interface
interface Foo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

let bar: Bar<Foo, Foo['name']> = {
    prop: "name", // Selected Foo.name: string
    value: '9',     // Should only allow strings
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about something similar, but `Foo['name']` is not known at compile time yet. Also, now `name` is duplicated which is also not really what I'd want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your usage example:

```
let bar: Bar<Foo> = {
    prop: "name", // Selected Foo.name: string
    value: 9,     // Should only allow strings
};
```

the compiler cannot infer we want the `name` property. It need another type parameter, as `Pick` utility type.

```
type PickEntry<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    prop: K; // Select a property of the type
    value: T[K]; // Provide the value of that property, this currently does not work
}
```

*Note: `PickEntry` is more explicit than `Foo`*

Then, we can detect invalid value type:

```
let nameEntry: PickEntry<Foo, 'name'> = {
    prop: "name",
    value: 9,
//  ~~~~~ Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
};
```