# Using union type with generic

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts a parameter which is an object consisting of a field (string) and arguments (object literal).

I'd like the arguments type check to be validated dependent on what the field is. I also wish to make a definition that can be extended wherever I needed (hence the generic).

Definition:

```
 export interface EventDefinition<
    TField extends string,
    TArgs extends any
  > {
    field: TField
    arguments: TArgs
  }
```

My function:

```
export const myFn =  (
  params:
    | EventDefinition<
        'actionOne',
        {
          id: string
        }
      >
    | EventDefinition<
        'actionTwo',
        {
          emailAddress: string
        }
      >
) => {
  const { args, field } = params

  switch(field) {
    case 'actionOne':
      console.log(args.id)
      break;
      case 'actionTwo':
      console.log(args.emailAddress)
      break;
  }
}
```

While the field property validates the args do not and result in errors (for ex with args.id):

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string }'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ emailAddress: string; }'.
```

How can I correctly define this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript will not guard one variable based on another, this is just not supported.

If you use the argument itself control flow analysis can determine the types appropriately

```
  switch(params.field) {
    case 'actionOne':
      console.log(params.arguments.id)
      break;
      case 'actionTwo':
      console.log(params.arguments.emailAddress)
      break;
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwHgDg9gTgLsAlgOziGAzAhgYxMAUQDcRUAREDFRORKZAHgChhXgAVAMURABsATUGDTJ+AZ2Bi4MFAHMANCzbsAgjFkTwI8cCzIAnkoB8wAN5LWVPvwBcHbtYu71AVwC2pOGLur1YpQC+TMHg0PDAOPRSwG76nMjAALysABRKEFgwWG7eTgA+hCTklNS09MxslcAA5LhlyADyyCDVilVs5u2ViLaS0nJOlUHtRvmFnhRUyDR0jINstTj17ADuUK3zrJ1drCBuWIi8Kvz8MCBi3n0yyLKbwMNVowCUSSbbYis0OAAWKRlZOQAdFYBC9tqwcFgxPhFvUmi0bPNIsgxFBeCBAbwoLI-plsmJAZlZO5PASek95gAjM5YADWAG4kVCYXVZqt1oj2sjUejMdjcQCCUSSagCXsDkcTmcLhT2tSQHTGawggEgA)

Comment: Shoot. I saw an answer by you regarding Mapping Interface which I think should work albeit losing some flex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj

Comment: @cyberwombat you already have a discriminated union, just as I suggested in the other answer. Your only issue is that you can't type guard on separate values, you need to keep everything in one variable