# Conditional props in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this conditional question, but can we do general types in TypeScript? I often have components like follows:

```
type Props = {
  title: string
  buttonLabel?: string
  onButtonClick?: () => void
}
```

So I can optionally provide a string for a button and if it's provided then I also should provide what happens to it on click. However I want `onButtonClick` to be mandatory if buttonLabel is provided. Some syntax like:

```
type Props = {
  title: string
  buttonLabel?: string
  onButtonClick<!buttonLabel>: () => void
}
```

Is this available in Typescript or any other language?

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj?

Comment: Kind of. I would like to be able to define it on a per prop basis instead of having to repeat all the types for each conditional type. Although this may be a sign of bad design/I may not know what I'm talking about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would combine a type that omits both with a type that requires both

```
type Props = {
  title: string;
} | {
  title: string;
  buttonLabel: string;
  onButtonClick: () => void;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make buttonLable and onButtonClick be mandatory together by making another object like this if I understood you correctly:

```
type Props = {
  title: string
  buttonLink?: string
  buttonData?: {label: string
                onButtonClick: () => void
                }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is a good way to do it! Pretty obvious, thank you!