# How to set conditional types for object properties

Tags: typescript

I have an object with two values. I would like to type check one value conditionally based on the value of its peer. I have looked at various solutions but I cannot get it to work how I would like it to.

I can do something like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950384/1241287)):

```
type TypeFruit = "apples" | "bananas";
type TypeMetal = "iron" | "copper";

type InterfaceItem =
  | {
      item: "fruit";
      type: TypeFruit;
    }
  | {
      event: "metal";
      type: TypeMetal;
    };

type ItemTypeParameters = InterfaceItem["type"];

type Item = {
  item: "fruit" | "metal";
  type: ItemTypeParameters;
};
```

But that produces:

```
// ✅ Correct
assignItem({
  item: "fruit",
  type: "apples",
});

// ✅ Correct
assignItem({
  item: "fruit",
  type: "copper",
});
```

What I would like to do is set up the code so that the outcome would be like this:

```js
// ✅ Correct
assignItem({
  item: "fruit",
  type: "apples",
});

// ❌ Wrong
assignItem({
  item: "fruit",
  type: "copper",
});
```

Is there a way to do this? I've looked at ConditionalTypes, which seems like what I would want, but found them confusing and it seemed like they were for other scenarios like extending types conditionally.

Comment: `InterfaceItem` is already giving you the shape you want, isn't it? Just use it instead of the `ItemTypeParameters` and the `type Item`

Comment: Yes! You are correct. Haha, I was too far into it — couldn't see straight. Thank you for the clarity!

Comment: Happy to accept an answer if you want to post it. Otherwise I'll just delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original `InterfaceItem` is already giving you the shape you're looking for - where `item: "fruit"` is necessarily paired with (and only paired with) a `TypeFruit`. All you need is that, and nothing else.

```
type TypeFruit = "apples" | "bananas";
type TypeMetal = "iron" | "copper";
type InterfaceItem =
  | {
      item: "fruit";
      type: TypeFruit;
    }
  | {
      event: "metal";
      type: TypeMetal;
    };

declare const assignItem: (item: InterfaceItem) => null;

assignItem({ // Works
  item: "fruit",
  type: "apples",
});

assignItem({ // Fails
  item: "fruit",
  type: "copper",
});
```