# typescript How can you infer the type of one argument from the type of another

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, echarts

```
type ChartType = 'bar' | 'line' | 'pie';


interface PropsType {
  type: EChartType;
  xData: **** ;
  seriesData: ****  ;
}
const props = defineProps<PropsType>();
```

how to do

When `ChartType = 'bar'`, `xData` has type `string[]` and `seriesData` has type `number[]`.
When `ChartType = 'line'`, `xData` has type `Array<string|number>` and `seriesData` has type `string[]`.
When `ChartType = 'pie'`, `xData` has type `number[]` and `seriesData` has type `{value:string,name:string}[]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Type of a property dependent on another property within the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj)

Comment: I don't know how to write it, can you help me implement it

Comment: Please read about [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer to your question.

```
type TPropsType = {
        type: "bar"
        xData: string[]
        seriesData: number[]
    } | {
        type: "line"
        xData: Array<string|number>
        seriesData: string[]
    } | {
        type: 'pie'
        xData: number[]
        seriesData: {value:string,name:string}[]
    }
```